# Collapsing daily longitudinal data into monthly observations by ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, longitudinal

I have longitudinal data with >100 rows per subject representing daily observations. I want to collapse columns, by subject ID, into monthly observations (i.e. have multiple rows per ID that are summarizing every 30 rows (days) of data).

How can you specify such groupings of days using dplyr?

Also of note, all subjects have different total number of days

Edit: data sample below

```
df<-structure(list(ID = structure(c(100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 
                                    100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 
                                    100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087)), time = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 
                                                                                                                         4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)), 
                   BMI = structure(c(20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 
                                     20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 
                                     20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06)), Dis = structure(c(0, 
                                                                                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
                   Drug1 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), Drug2 = structure(c(1, 
                                                                                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                            -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: it would be very helpful if you posted any sample data :)

Comment: Create a `month` column to group by. (Maybe a `year` column too, if your data spans multiple years.) You can use the `lubridate` functions `month()` and `year()` to easily extract the month and year from a date. If you need more help than that, please provide some sample data (use `dput()` to make it copy/pasteable!) and the desired output.

Comment: Please share a sample of your data with the dput() function so that we can give you a proper answer.

Comment: I added an example of the data structure. There are no dates, just days in the time column

Answer (score 1):

I would `group_by` `ID` and a new `times` variable where you can specify the bins with `time %/% 30` for 30 rows. Since your example data has only a few rows I set this to `5`. Since each respondent has a different amount of `times` we need to record `first_time` and `last_time` to then overwrite `times` as `x - y` times where x and y are first and last time.

In the `across` call you would need to specify the way you want to aggregate the data, below I choose `mean`. In case you want to get the `mean` of `BMI` and the `max` value of `Drug1` you would need to specify each column in a separate function call.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID, times = time %/% 5) %>% 
  summarise(across(BMI:Drug2, mean),
         time_first = first(time),
         time_last = last(time)
         ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(times = paste0(time_first, "-", time_last)) %>% 
  select(-c(time_first, time_last))

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'ID'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>       ID times   BMI   Dis Drug1 Drug2
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 100087 0-4    20.1     0     1     1
#> 2 100087 5-9    20.1     0     1     1
#> 3 100087 10-14  20.1     0     1     1
#> 4 100087 15-19  20.1     0     1     1

# OPs data
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087, 100087)), time = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)), BMI = structure(c(20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06, 20.06)), Dis = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), Drug1 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), Drug2 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>